# How to replace 2-byte ASCII code with 1-byte hexadecimal

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm developing with arduino, and I'm wondering how to change the hexadecimal 2 bytes received with RS485 to ASCII code each and then change the string to 1 byte hexadecimal.

HEX 0x30 = ASCII '0'
HEX 0x31 = ASCII '1'
I want to combine the above two and make it 0x01.

Below is an example.

```
HEX 0x42, 0x38 = ASCII 'B', '8' = 0xB8
HEX 0x30, 0x41 = ASCII '0', 'A' = 0x0A
HEX 0x34, 0x39 = ASCII '4', '9' = 0x49
HEX 0x44, 0x44 = ASCII 'D', 'D' = 0xDD
```

My current code is like this.

```
    uint16_t DATA1 = ((MFC_Respons[7] - 0x30) * 16) + (MFC_Respons[8] - 0x30);
    uint16_t DATA2 = ((MFC_Respons[9] - 0x30) * 16) + (MFC_Respons[10] - 0x30);
    uint16_t DATA3 = ((MFC_Respons[11] - 0x30) * 16) + (MFC_Respons[12] - 0x30);
    uint16_t DATA4 = ((MFC_Respons[13] - 0x30) * 16) + (MFC_Respons[14] - 0x30);
```

help me....

Comment: Your code should work. Do you want to write that in a loop? What is your problem with that? Do you want the result in different variables or in one container? Why do you use `uint16_t` if you specifically want it in 1 byte, which is `uint8_t`?

Comment: Instead of magic numbers you should use character value: `-0x30` should be `-'0'`. But your code does only handle decimal digits. You need to check if a hex digit is above `'9'` and then subtract `-'A' + 10` instead

Comment: `'A' - '0'` is not 10 in most character encodings, and there are some where `'0'` is not 48.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'hexadecimal 2 bytes'. Bytes are bytes,. Hex is a representation. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do is write a function that converts one hexadecimal digit into the appropriate value. For example

```
int hex_value(char digit)
{
    if (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9')
        return digit - '0'; // decimal digit
    else if (digit >= 'a' && digit <= 'f')
        return digit - 'a' + 10; // lower case hexadecimal digit
    else if (digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'F')
        return digit - 'A' + 10; // upper case hexadecimal digit
    else
        return -1;          // error, don't care
}
```

Then it's trivial to use that function to do the conversion you require

e.g.

```
uint16_t DATA1 = 16*hex_value(MFC_Respons[7]) + hex_value(MFC_Respons[8]);
```

Note there is no error checking in this code. Only you will know if that is a significant issue or not.

Also this code does assume contiguous encoding of alphabetic characters, but the chances of that not being true are very small indeed.

Comment: ASCII defines the code values of bytes '0' = 0x30 ... 'f' = 0x66 . That's not an issue here. I'd rather think about the data type of the result and error checking

Comment: "code does assume contiguous encoding of alphabetic characters" --> is more like "code does assume contiguous encoding of alphabetic characters A to F" as in ASCII and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (which is not continuous A-Z).  Good job.

Answer (score 1):

If you prioritize readability/portability over performance (you do per definition not prioritize performance, because: Arduino, C++), then maybe drop all magic numbers and drop the manual parsing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  char some_input[] = 
  {
    'B', '8',
    '0', 'A',
    '4', '9',
    'D', 'D',
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(some_input); i+=2)
  {
    static char tmp[3] = {0}; // the 3rd byte will always be \0 here
    tmp[0] = some_input[i];
    tmp[1] = some_input[i+1];

    uint8_t result = strtoul(tmp, NULL, 16);

    printf("%c %c -> %3d dec, %2X hex\n", 
           some_input[i], 
           some_input[i+1], 
           result, 
           result);
  }
}
```

This can be expanded with additional error handling of `strtoul` to the point where it can actually serve as a decent error handler for of the incoming ASCII stream. Now it should be mentioned that `strtoul` and 32 bit arithmetic isn't ideal for 8 bit microcontrollers. But neither are most of the Arduino libs.

Comment: Could use `char tmp[3] = {some_input[i], some_input[i+1] }`.  Not sure why answer uses `static`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Mostly because it's for an 8-bitter and you'll want to avoid placing buffers on the stack. Just a habit, it doesn't affect the performance much.